# Get session data woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, session, woocommerce, cart

I am using a plugin (Fancy product designer) who allows me to customise some product. The finished product store a data uri image and I think it's stored in the woocommerce session or cart data.

So i'm searching a way to get the data to retrieve the uri image and build a custom hook with it.

How to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried asking the Fancy Product Designer team? And/or reading their documentation?

Comment: Yes already tried but they don't answered me. Also they only do documentation for their jquery version not woocommerce version

Comment: Well that stinks. I don't know that extension at all, but your best bet might be to do something like a `var_dump(WC()->cart->get_cart());` to see everything in the cart. That might help you find what you are looking for.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?